# vertical and horizontal lines draw through plt.plot() method --Global API--Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am practicing basic **matplotlib plotting**, but can't understand these **axis** for **vertical** and **horizontal lines**.

```
plt.plot([x, y, z], [x, y, z])
```

Actual example,

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.title('My Nice Plot')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)  # rows, columns, panel selected
plt.plot(x, x ** 2)
plt.plot([0, 0, 0], [-10, 0, 100])  <<<<<<======= ???????
plt.legend(['X^2', 'Vertical Line'])
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('X Squared')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(x, -1 * (x ** 2))
plt.plot([-10, 0, 10], [-50, -50, -50])  <<<<<<======= ???????
plt.legend(['-X^2', 'Horizontal Line'])

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('X Squared')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs for plt.plot()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html):

> Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
>
> Call signature:
>
> > `plot([x], y, [fmt], *, data=None, **kwargs)`
>
> The coordinates of the points or line nodes are given by x, y.

As you can see, the first argument to `plt.plot()` is a list of x-coordinates, and the second argument is a list of y-coordinates.

So, with `plt.plot([0, 0, 0], [-10, 0, 100])` you are giving lists of x-coordinates (`[0, 0, 0]`) and y-coordinates (`[-10, 0, 100]`) to be plotted, not as you suggested two lists of `(x, y, z)` coordinates.

In the vertical line, all your x-coordinates are 0 with y-coordinates of -10, 0 and 100; in this example, the middle point (with coordinates (0, 0)) is unnecessary, you could just draw a line between (0, -10) and (0, 100) using `plt.plot([0, 0], [-10, 100])`.

Similarly for the horizontal line, you could reduce `plt.plot([-10, 0, 10], [-50, -50, -50])` to `plt.plot([-10, 10], [-50, -50])` to draw a line at y=-50 between x=-10 and x=10.